# What Does SET CSPACE=1 Do in SQL/KBSQL

Tags: sql

What does this do?  I'm using KBSQL but suspect this instance would be identical to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSPACE` is a column modifier to control the display format in a `SELECT` or `WRITE` clause, and is mutually-exclusive with the modifier `COLUMN`. It takes an integer, and controls the number of blank characters to display between columns.

`SET CSPACE = 1` creates one space between each column.

Comment: I believe it's exclusive to KB_SQL.